# New import of Observables since 5.5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Since rxjs 5.5's change with [<s>"lettable operators"</s>](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md) ["pipeable operators"](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) it is recommended to stop importing from `rxjs/add/operator/*` to allow for proper tree shaking. Does this also apply for Observables like `rxjs/add/observable/of`? `rxjs/observable/of` exists but doesn't appear to provide the compatible typing.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem...

Comment: Should I avoid using `rxjs/add/observable/of` to allow for treeshaking?

Comment: Yes, since RxJS 5.5 it's better to use the pipable version for both operators and observables

Comment: But the documentation mentions nothing of observables? `rxjs/observable/of` isn't accepted by Typescript and `rxjs/observables` doesn't exist like with operators.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: @Ingo I linked this page in my question

Comment: `rxjs/observable/of` is not an operator, so it doesn't apply to to the pipeable changes. Same as `fromEvent` and etc.

Comment: @chybie But does including it imply that you can't tree-shake your code properly any more like it does with operators?